what does "runtime" mean in programming/software engineering?
I'm trying to understand what the term "runtime" means specifically in programming and software engineering.
The more research i do into the term, the more it seems it could mean several different things like

the space of time that the program is actually executing
the system runtime
the runtime environment
the runtime system
the runtime library

So when using the term "runtime" which of these is it referring to? Or maybe it's not referring to any of them, and it's referring to something completely different.
Also here is an example of what i mean in runtime on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime

"also here is an example of what i mean in runtime on wikipedia" - em, did you note that page does not contain any specific example. Quite the opposite, it is an disambiguation page, used for terms which can have different meanings.

Probably related: "Runtime", "run time", and "run-time"

The word runtime (and potentially also the homophonic two-word term run time or the compound term run-time) do have a variety of meanings in a computing context.

so when using the term "runtime" which of these is it referring to? or maybe it's not referring to any of them, and it's referring to something completely different.

You seem to be proceeding from the idea that only one meaning is possible. In fact, there are many meanings, and the same term can be used for all of them.
It would be possible to come up with a silly sentence like "the run-time of the runtime at runtime" which is nevertheless perfectly meaningful (if not perfectly clear).
The first run-time refers to the execution speed, the second refers to a library module which supports a particular programming language and is used in the execution of a compiled program, and the third refers to a time when the program is executing (as opposed to the time when it is compiling, or when it is stored but not running).
Which meaning is in use is to be determined by the reader in context.

A classic example of multiple meanings is Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

"You seem to be proceeding from the idea that only one meaning is possible. In fact, there are many meanings, and the same term can be used for all of them." – There is a good example in the OP's question itself, since the OP uses the term programming which has very different meanings in Software Engineering and TV.

@JörgWMittag, indeed it does, although at least in that case he could just say they are two completely different contexts - like iron in a foundry means something different to iron in a laundry. I think what seemed to surprise the OP is that, even within the same software context, one word can still have many meanings.

@PeterM, my favorite variation of that linguistic construct is the ship-shipping ship shipping shipping ships. Or truck-trucking trucks trucking trucking trucks.

Yes, it is an ambiguous term.
And as the case usually is with ambiguous terms, in order to disambiguate it you need to examine the context in which it is said.

If you see "during runtime", it means as the program it is running.

If you see "by the runtime", it means by the execution environment.

In the context of the C language, this is the C runtime library.

In the context of the Java language, this is the Java virtual machine and associated runtime libraries.




...and it goes on like that.

I think, it would be a good idea to also mention the garbage collector and the just-in-time compiler being part of the Java runtime. It gives a sense about how huge and influential a runtime can be.

Speaking from experience:
"Run time", two words, is most likely to refer to the actual time it takes the program to run.  This might be time as measured by a clock, or something more abstract like "The run time of the algorithm is O(n^2)" (proportional to the square of the size of the input).
"run-time", hyphenated, usually means "when the program executes, as opposed to when it's compiled."  For example: "Automated testing is a good way of turning run-time crashes into compile-time errors," or "A correct program will often still crash at run-time on a system with faulty hardware."
"runtime," one word, generally means the supporting software and libraries necessary for the program to run, but, typically, NOT the hardware or operating system.  For example: "The Java runtime has always been faster than the Python runtime, but the gap is closing," or "To run this program on Windows, you will need the latest version of the .NET runtime."  It would not be idiomatic to say "This program was written for Windows XP, so it crashes in the Windows 11 runtime."  You'd just say "it crashes on Windows 11."
Your question refers to "the system runtime," "the runtime environment," "the runtime system," and "the runtime library" and these are all variations on the theme of "the supporting software the program needs."  By convention and tradition, different languages or even different individual authors tend to use different phrasing for the similar support software.
There are shades of nuance.  With Java, you might say "the system runtime" to describe the version of Java that is installed globally across the operating system, as distinct from "the application runtime" or "the local runtime," the specific version of Java that you have installed yourself to use with your program.  In this case "system" functions as an adjective.
Similarly, "the runtime environment" would often be interpreted to mean the currently active configuration, especially, environment variables.  You would never say "the runtime system" to mean this.  As with fluency in a foreign language, the best way to learn this jargon is simply to gain personal experience with it.

I feel like if it would be good to add etymology and emphasize how runtime is the supporting software the program needs which is found and connected to when it runs. Or put another way, that this supporting software isn't included during compile-time -- it lives on the user's computer (which is way down in your 2nd-to-last P). Ideally that would just be a few words, but I'm not seeing the best place.

It is most useful to think of it in the negative sense.
Run-time == "not compile-time"

The most interesting and tricky use of run-time is in contrast with compile-time, and is often about bugs. Runtime is when the customer is running your program, and a bug crashes it and makes you look bad. Compile-time is (basically) when you, the programmer, are still writing it. In compile-time, the same bug makes a red squiggle under part of a line and tells us why that thing could be a problem. In this sense, run-time means "bad" and compile-time means "good" (to be clear, runtime libraries and runtime environment and runtime system are their own different things).
For example, "C#'s bulky rules for inheritance allow compile-time checking" is saying that, sure, C# can take longer to type out, but the trade-off is it underlines possible errors right away. Whereas "python has super-easy polymorphism, but it's checked run-time" means sure, Python is faster to write, but there's a bad side to that. To be more specific, if you say "giftWrap(x)" but forget that x could be a cat, C# will underline it right away(*), and warn you about cats. Python won't. The program will run fine when you test it, until you finally run a test with cats and it crashes. Same mistake in both cases, but when when it's detected run-time, it took longer to find and we could have missed it.
Obviously, why we say "compile-time" needs explaining. Back in the day you typed programs in basically notepad. The computer never thought of your words as a program until you ran it through a compiler (a program). That tried to read it, yelled at you if it couldn't, turned it into 0's and 1's, and later optimized it and gave helpful warnings. The time that took was "compile-time", and the messages it gave were compile-time errors. But today the compiler is split. The IDE constantly runs a version of half (the part that checks if it can read your program, and the part looking for possible logic bugs). That's how you get the red squiggles. The other half runs when you press the "Create executable" button (smashes into low-level code and optimizes). Out of tradition we still say "compile-time" as if the compiler ran the old way.
It's not always about errors, it's the same idea. For example, "Java compiles into bytecode which is interpreted runtime" means that some of the work is done before the customer gets a Java program, which is good, but then the rest is done while the customer is running it, which makes it a tiny bit slower, so is bad. Or "Overloading operators is handled compile-time" is saying a good thing. You might think w1+w2 makes a program pause in runtime and decide between 3+6 or 'cup'+'cake'. But here "compile-time" is saying it can figure that out in advance, which makes it run faster.
Once you're happy with compile-time vs. run-time, you should be able to puzzle out other uses. For example, a compile-time library is obviously a library added to the program ahead of time, whereas a run-time library means it somehow gets it when you run the program. Knowing that much is probably enough to read a decent article about them.
(*) Assuming your program doesn't define a way to gift wrap cats. If it does, than no errors and never mind.

The phrase "the same bug" sounds wrong. If it's a compile-time error, how can it survive until run-time?

@RolandIllig Hmmm...I suppose "mistake" is a better word. My thinking was that when the IDE says "cat does not implement IGiftWrappable" it's preventing what could be a bug later -- "pre bug". But it does feel odd to call something a bug which has no chance to make it's way into the executable.
